Optional property on typescript union type is marked as required
I have the below type:
class CachedLegalEntityNameCheckResult {
  constructor(
    readonly code: number,
    readonly status: 'verified' | 'unverified',
    readonly message?: string | ListOfErrors
  ) {}
}

class BusinessInfo<TPersonInfo, TCompany = Company<TPersonInfo>> {
  legalEntityName?: string
  businessName?: string
  business?: Business<TPersonInfo, TCompany>
  businessAddress?: Address
  businessPhone?: string
  serviceDescription?: string
  businessCodes?: BusinessCodes
  numberOfEmployees?: number
  rangeOfEmployees?: RangeOfEmployees
  isLegalEntityNameVerified?: boolean
  legalEntityNameDetails?: CachedLegalEntityNameCheckResult
}

using those two, I am making a new type:
type BusinessInfoPage = Omit<
  Required<BusinessInfo<UnsafePersonInfo>>,
  'business' | 'legalEntityNameCheckDetails'
> & {
  business: FrontBusiness
} & { isGovt: boolean } & { legalEntityNameCheckDetails?: CachedLegalEntityNameCheckResult }

The problem with the new BusinessInfoPage type is that legalEntityNameCheckDetails is required, whereas I need this property to be optional.
I tried a bunch of tricks, including Pick. Yet, somehow my type has legalEntityNameCheckDetails as required, or not at all.
What am I doing wrong? How do I fix the issue?

Please [edit] this code to be a [mre] we can copy and paste into our IDEs and see what you're seeing, without unrelated errors. Right now there are a lot of private/third-party types that are undeclared and thus cause lots of errors you're not asking about. Please declare them or, even better, replace them with native types.

If the legalEntityNameCheckDetails should be optional, you don't have to omit it, you can just override it to be optional.
type BusinessInfoPage = Omit<BusinessInfo<UnsafePersonInfo>, 'business'> & {
  business: FrontBusiness
  isGovt: boolean
  legalEntityNameCheckDetails?: CachedLegalEntityNameCheckResult
}

In the example below, if isGovt is true, you don't need to supply business or legalEntityNameCheckDetails.
const govPage: BusinessInfoPage = {
  business: { businessName: '' },
  isGovt: true,
}

const businessPage: BusinessInfoPage = {
  business: { businessName: '' },
  isGovt: false,
  legalEntityNameCheckDetails: new CachedLegalEntityNameCheckResult(
    200,
    'verified',
  ),
}

I added these faux-types to get TypeScript to be happy:
interface Address {}
interface Business<TPersonInfo, TCompany> {}
interface BusinessCodes {}
interface Company<TPersonInfo> {}
interface Error {}
interface FrontBusiness {}
interface RangeOfEmployees {}
interface UnsafePersonInfo {}

type ListOfErrors = Error[]


isGovt and legalEntityNameCheckDetails are independent of one another. meaning whether isGovt = true or false, legalEntityNameCheckDetails should be optional.

@IgorShmukler then this is a much easier task. I updated my response.

  Required<BusinessInfo<UnsafePersonInfo>>,
  'business' | 'legalEntityNameCheckDetails'
> & {
  business: FrontBusiness
  isGovt: boolean
  legalEntityNameCheckDetails?: CachedLegalEntityNameCheckResult
}``` is not working.

The issue is not with constructing the objects. Typescript does not like `businessInfo.legalEntityNameDetails = undefined` and/or `delete businessInfo.legalEntityNameDetails`
